# Workflow hosted inside WorkflowApplication, aborting on persistence

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I have been trying to resolve a somewhat intermittent issue working with a long running state machine running inside a WorkflowApplication. I can step through the workflow and this behaves as expected, transitioning through the states as expected, then a bookmark is reached which then persists the workflow. However, the workflow is then aborted and I get the following message:

*The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance owner registration for owner ID 'ba26f4e9-f38b-4179-aa09-31ab9f8af337' has become invalid. This error indicates that the in-memory copy of all instances locked by this owner have become stale and should be discarded, along with the InstanceHandles. Typically, this error is best handled by restarting the host*.

The Sql Instance store is initialised as follows:

```
 SqlStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlInstanceStore"].ConnectionString);
 SqlStore.HostLockRenewalPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
 SqlStore.InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteAll;
 handle = SqlStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
 InstanceView sqlView = SqlStore.Execute(handle, new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));                   
 SqlStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = sqlView.InstanceOwner;
 WorkflowHost = new WorkflowApplication(WorkflowDefinition, inputs);
 WorkflowHost.Run();
```

To create the bookmark:

```
context.CreateBookmark(bkmk, OnResume);
```

The exception doesn't really provide enough information to help troubleshooting this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by using an overload of the instance store where I am now passing a new GUID. Need to understand this a bit more.

```
 handle = SqlStore.CreateInstanceHandle(Guid.NewGuid());
```